# Integral to floating point type (upcast) in cxx11

Tags: templates, c++11

Is there an automatic floating point (template) placeholder for up-casts of e.g. int types? I mean a class or something related which takes a parameter and return a proper sized floating point type which considers automatic upcasts.

I don't like the line, because in case of an int the right type for conversion would be a double.

```
    if(is_equal((float)var_high, (float)var_low)) {
```

in this example:

```
template <class T>
T linear_interpolate(const T &low_output, const T &high_output,
                     const T &var_value,
                     const T &var_low, const T &var_high)
{
    if (var_value <= var_low) {
        return low_output;
    }
    if (var_value >= var_high) {
        return high_output;
    }
    // avoid zero divisions or zero like divisions
    if(is_equal((float)var_high, (float)var_low)) {
        return low_output;
    }

    T p = (var_value - var_low) / (var_high - var_low);
    return low_output + p * (high_output - low_output);
}
```

Comment: "in case of an int the right type for conversion would be a double": Why?

Comment: @101010 I guess it means that a float wouldn't have enough precision (considering 32 bit for both).

Comment: Was more looking for a keyword, function or class which inserts automatically the right type (float, double, long double ..)

Comment: If T is int your code will perform integer division and return an int too. It's what you want? Maybe you should specialize your template for integer types.

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the difference (high-low) to the minimum representable for that type:

```
if (var_high - var_low <= std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon())
```

You'll also need to change the arithmetic to work with `int` - your temporary variable `p` will always be zero if `T` is an integer type.

Full code, with a few tests:

```
#include <limits>

template <class T>
T linear_interpolate(const T &low_output, const T &high_output,
                     const T &var_value,
                     const T &var_low, const T &var_high)
{
    if (var_value <= var_low) {
        return low_output;
    }
    if (var_value >= var_high) {
        return high_output;
    }
    // avoid zero divisions or zero like divisions
    if (var_high - var_low <= std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()) {
        return low_output;
    }

    return low_output
         + (var_value - var_low) * (high_output - low_output) / (var_high - var_low);
}


#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << linear_interpolate(1, 10, 6, 0, 9) << std::endl;
    std::cout << linear_interpolate(1, 10, 0, 0, 0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << linear_interpolate(1, 10, 1, 0, 1) << std::endl;

    std::cout << linear_interpolate(1.0, 10.0, 6.0, 0.0, 9.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << linear_interpolate(1.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << linear_interpolate(1.0, 10.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0) << std::endl;
}
```

I haven't included the tests for `value<low` etc, as I assume you already have those.

---

You probably ought to consider that a linear interpolation is likely to want different types for input and output:

```
template <class T, class S=T>
S linear_interpolate(const S &low_output, const S &high_output,
                     const T &var_value,
                     const T &var_low, const T &var_high)
```

Comment: If the user would insert integers you would compare a hard integer zero with epsilon (floating point). This may result in a up-cast.

Comment: @dgrat, not true - `std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()` returns a `T`, so there can never be a conversion involved.